# index dataframe replacement from other dataframe pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have been playing with this for hours and it just doesnt do it.
I am simply trying to replace the index of a particular dataframe based on the index from a another dataframe. To do this i do it like this A.index = B.index
But all im getting is:
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 22 elements, new values have 29 elements

Firstly i have this pandas code which reads csv files:

```
%pylab inline
import pandas as pd
import xlrd
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

first_data = pd.read_csv('sample.txt', sep='\t',skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4], header=None, index_col=[0])
```

Then i have a second DataFrame which reads from an xlsx file, my aim is to simply replace the index of this file from the index of nai_data using this technique A.index = B.index.

I have two solutions but neither works, here is what i have done:

Solution 1:

```
dtype = pd.read_excel('Type.xlsx', header=None)
#dtype.index = first_data.index
print dtype
```

Solution 2:

```
xls_file=pd.ExcelFile('Type.xlsx', header=None)
table=xls_file.parse('Sheet1', header=None)
#table.index = first_data.index
print table
```

Upon printing they both look like this:

```
        0
0   ghost
1   ghost
2   ghost
3   noise
4   noise
5   noise
6   noise
7   noise
8   ghost
9   ghost
10  ghost
11  ghost
12  ghost
13  noise
14  noise
15  noise
16  noise
17  noise
18  ghost
19  ghost
20  ghost
21  ghost
22  ghost
23  noise
24  noise
25  noise
26  noise
27  noise
```

If i activate the A.index = B.index code it gives a

```
ValueError: Length mismatch: Expected axis has 22 elements, new values have 29 elements
```

Am i missing something?

Comment: The error message says that the length of both indexes is not equal (22 vs 29 elements), so you cannot just assign it. So well, is this the case? Did you check the length of both? (`len(A.index), len(B.index)`)